# Replace exactly one pixel in an image and put it in another image via Swift

Tags: swift, image, opengl-es, core-image

Simply put, if I have an image, `I` and another image `J`, I want to replace the RGB value at a position `I(t,s)` and assign that pixel to `J(t,s)`. How might I do this in Core Image, or using a custom kernel?

This seems like it might not be an easy thing to do, considering the way Core Image works. However, I was wondering maybe there was a way to extract the value of the pixel at `(t,s)`, create an image `K` as large as `J` with just that pixel, and then overlay `J` with `K` only at that one point. Just an idea, hopefully there's a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set just **one** pixel, you can create a small color kernel that compares a passed target coordinate with the current coordinate and colors the output appropriately. For example:

```
let kernel = CIColorKernel(string:
"kernel vec4 setPixelColorAtCoord(__sample pixel, vec2 targetCoord, vec4 targetColor)" +
    "{" +
    "   return int(targetCoord.x) == int(destCoord().x) && int(targetCoord.y) == int(destCoord().y) ? targetColor : pixel; " +
    "}"
)
```

Then, given an image, let's say a solid red:

```
let image = CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0))
    .imageByCroppingToRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 640, height: 640))
```

If we want to set the pixel at 500, 100 to blue:

```
let targetCoord = CIVector(x: 500, y: 100)
let targetColor = CIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1)
```

The following will create a `CIImage` named `final` with a single blue pixel in a sea of red:

```
let args = [image, targetCoord, targetColor]
let final = kernel?.applyWithExtent(image.extent, arguments: args)
```

If you want to draw more than one pixel, this may not be the best solution though.

Simon

Comment: Simon to the rescue! Love your book by the way!

Comment: Quick question actually -- I'd like to reference the color that I'm using from an image. Instead of doing `vec4 targetColor`, what if I have another __sample to get the color from. I could use `vec4 targetColor = sample(pixel2, targetCoord)` to tell what color to reference from or something.

Comment: You could pass both images into your kernel and get the source pixel color with `vec2 imageSpaceCoord = samplerTransform(xyzImage, destCoord()); vec4 targetColor = sample(image, imageSpaceCoord);` - where `xyzImage` is the image you're sampling from. Thanks for the kind words about the book :)

Comment: Simon, would you have a better solution than this to draw a single pixel in an image? This is fast for just a few pixels, but the reason I ask is because in a filter I'm creating(local laplacian filters) one DOES have to draw pixels from various different images to a single target. You can imagine how much memory/performance is lost if you chain this kernel thousands of times because its saving data for the entire image, when really only one pixel is changed at a time.

Comment: Hi - take a look at the `extent` parameter: you don't need to apply a kernel to an entire image.

Answer (score 2):

I created a useful helper for handling images by pixel. It basically creates an RGBA image context, copies the image into it (so that we can work with the image data as it's jpeg or something), and gets the raw data buffer of it. This is the class I made:

```
public final class RGBAPixels {
    static let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue
    static let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    public typealias Pixel = (r: UInt8, g: UInt8, b: UInt8, a: UInt8)

    let context : CGContext
    let pointer : UnsafeMutablePointer<Pixel>

    public let width : Int
    public let height : Int

    public let range : (x: Range<Int>, y: Range<Int>)

    /// Generates an image from the current pixels
    public var CGImage : CGImageRef? {
        return CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)
    }

    public init?(CGImage: CGImageRef) {
        width = CGImageGetWidth(CGImage)
        height = CGImageGetHeight(CGImage)

        range = (0..<width, 0..<height)

        guard let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(
            nil, width, height, 8, sizeof(Pixel) * width,
            RGBAPixels.colorSpace, RGBAPixels.bitmapInfo)
        else { return nil }

        self.context = context

        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: width, height: height))
        CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, CGImage)

        pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer(CGBitmapContextGetData(context))
    }


    public subscript (x: Int, y: Int) -> Pixel {
        get {
            assert(range.x ~= x && range.y ~= y, "Pixel position (\(x), \(y)) is out of the bounds \(range))")
            return pointer[y * width + x]
        }
        set {
            assert(range.x ~= x && range.y ~= y, "Pixel position (\(x), \(y)) is out of the bounds \(range))")
            pointer[y * width + x] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

It *is* useable by itself, but you might want to have some more convenience:

```
public protocol Image {
    var CGImage : CGImageRef? { get }
}

public extension Image {
    public var pixels : RGBAPixels? {
        return CGImage.flatMap(RGBAPixels.init)
    }

    public func copy(@noescape modifying : (pixels: RGBAPixels) -> Void) -> CGImageRef? {
        return pixels.flatMap{ pixels in
            modifying(pixels: pixels)
            return pixels.CGImage
        }
    }
}

extension CGImage : Image {
    public var CGImage: CGImageRef? { return self }
}

#if os(iOS)

import class UIKit.UIImage

extension UIImage : Image {}

extension RGBAPixels {
    public var image : UIImage? {
        return CGImage.map(UIImage.init)
    }
}

#elseif os(OSX)

import class AppKit.NSImage

extension NSImage : Image {
    public var CGImage : CGImageRef? {
        var rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        return CGImageForProposedRect(&rect, context: nil, hints: nil)
    }
}

extension RGBAPixels {
    public var image : NSImage? {
        return cgImage.flatMap{ img in
            NSImage(CGImage: img, size: CGSize(width: width, height: height))
        }
    }
}

#endif
```

It is useable like this:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "image")!
let pixels = image.pixels!

// Add a red square
for x in 10..<15 {
    for y in 10..<15 {
        pixels[x, y] = (255, 0, 0, 255)
    }
}

let modifiedImage = pixels.image

// Copy the image, while changing the pixel at (10, 10) to be blue
let otherImage = UIImage(named: "image")!.copy{ $0[10, 10] = (0, 255, 0, 255) }


let a = UIImage(named: "image")!.pixels!
let b = UIImage(named: "image")!.pixels!

// Set the pixel at (10, 10) of a to the pixel at (20, 20) of b
a[10, 10] = b[20, 20]

let result = a.image!
```

I unwrapped for the demonstration, don't actually do this an your app.

The implementation is as fast as it can get with the CPU. If you need to modify lots of images in more complicated ways than just copying, you may want to use CoreImage instead.

I made this work with both OSX's `NSImage`s *and* iOS's `UIImage`s.

Comment: This is great, however I would love an alternative in Core Image, which is what I've been primarily working in. I think it may be a bit inefficient to convert to and from UIImage to do this one step.

Comment: @DavidSacco I see, I thought so. Well if someone is searching for a CPU version he can find it here :D

Comment: i need some help, Can you please help me out ?
As in below line i got error : "No exact matches in call to initializer"

        pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Pixel>(CGBitmapContextGetData(context))