# CIFilter - Sample from within 0-1 range

Tags: core-image, cifilter, imagefilter

`CIFilter` uses a different sampling syntax than GLSL (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CIKernelLangRef/ci_gslang_ext.html).

Instead of the clear `texture2D(texture, position)` where position is in `[0, 1]*[0, 1]`, `CIFilter` uses a different coordinate system. It's works ok for sampling the pixel corresponding to the output position, because `CIFilter` gives you some functions that let you do:

```
sample(texture, samplerTransform(texture, destCoord()))
```

Ugly but fine.

I want to use a texture as a filter function, ie do things like

```
vec3 color = ...;
color.r = texture2D(filterTexture, vec2(color.r, 0.333)).r;
```

So I really need to be able to sample from a 0-1 scale. Any idea of how to do this within `CIFilter` ?

I've tried doing things as weird as:

```
vec2 imageSize = samplerTransform(filterTexture, samplerSize(filterTexture));
vec2 imageOffset = samplerTransform(filterTexture, vec2(0.0, 0.0));
color.r = sample(filterTexture, vec2(color.r, 0.333) * imageSize + imageOffset).r;
```

to no avail.

Comment: `destCoord()` returns the working space pixel that's being computed. Think of an image as an N x M image, `destCoord().x` returns the column and `destCoord().y` returns the row (both of these are floats). When working with `samplerCoord()`, your coordinates are in sampler space are are on [0,1]x[0,1]. I hope this helps, you are on the right track by using `sample`, it is very similiar to texture2D.

Comment: If it helps, you might want to play around with a dummy example to get the feel how things work in the kernel laguange, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547360/replace-exactly-one-pixel-in-an-image-and-put-it-in-another-image-via-swift for some code to play with just one pixel at a time so you can get a really good idea of where things are going. It helped me out, also helped me simplify my own code.