# Use output of a reduction CIFilter as color input for another filter

Tags: metal, core-image, cifilter, ciimage

I'm new to CoreImage / Metal, so my apologies in advance if my question is naive. I spent a week going over the CoreImage documentation and examples and I couldn't figure this one out.

Suppose I have a reduction filter such as CIAreaAverage which outputs a 1x1 image. Is it possible to convert that image into a color that I can pass as an argument of another CIFilter? I'm aware that I can do this by rendering the CIAreaAverage output into a CVPixelBuffer, but I'm trying to do this in one render pass.

**Edit #1 (Clarification):**

Let's say I want to correct the white balance by allowing the user to sample from an image a gray pixel:

```swift
let pixelImage = inputImage.applyingFilter("CICrop", arguments: [
  "inputRectangle": CGRect(origin: pixelCoordinates, size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) 
])

// We know now that the extent of pixelImage is 1x1. 
// Do something to convert the image into a pixel to be passed as an argument in the filter below.
let pixelColor = ???

let outputImage = inputImage.applyingFilter("CIWhitePointAdjust", arguments: [
  "inputColor": pixelColor
])
```

Is there a way to tell the `CIContext` to convert the 1x1 `CIImage` into `CIColor`?

Comment: Last try to help, sorry. Does something in this point you in the right direction? (Look at the second answer too.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547360/replace-exactly-one-pixel-in-an-image-and-put-it-in-another-image-via-swift I really do think this is basically a CoreImage issue you can work out without any concern for Metal or OpenGl.

Comment: That answer is similar to the approach I'm currently following. I'm creating a UInt8 array for the RGBA values and rendering the pixel to it using a CIContext. The problem with this approach is that this render must happen during the CIImage creation, and not during the actual render, which is inefficient. I'm struggling to believe that CoreImage doesn't have a better way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the result of `CIAreaAverage` in a *custom* `CIFilter` (i.e. you don't need it for a `CIColor` parameter), you can directly pass it as a `CIImage` to that filter and read the value via `sampler` in the kernel:

```
extern "C" float4 myKernel(sampler someOtherInput, sampler average) {
    float4 avg = average.sample(float2(0.5, 0.5)); // average only contains one pixel, so always sample that
    // ...
}
```

You can also call `.clampedToExtent()` on the average `CIImage` before you pass it to another filter/kernel. This will cause Core Image to treat the average image as if it were infinitely large, containing the same value everywhere. Then it doesn't matter at which coordinate you sample the value. This might be useful if you want to use the average value in a custom `CIColorKernel`.

Comment: Thanks Frank, this is helpful. This works great with a custom CIFilter, but obviously not with existing CIFilters such as `CIWhitePointAdjust`.

Comment: Have you, by chance, tried to pass the average image to the `inputColor` parameter as-is? I wonder if Core Image would detect the type of the value and act accordingly. I know that they allow things like that for some parameters, but their docs are very lacking, unfortunately.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried before I entered this rabbit hole. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Something you can do that doesn't involve Metal is use CoreImage itself. Let's say you want a 640x640 image of the output from `CIAreaAverage` that is called `ciPixel`:

```
let crop = CIFilter(name: "CICrop")
crop?.setValue(ciPixel, forKey: "inputImage")
crop?.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 640, w: 640), forKey: "inputRectangle")
ciOutput = crop?.outputImage
```

Comment: Thanks @dfd. Perhaps I wasn't very clear in my post. I'm not looking to expand the size of the average area output. I'm looking to convert the CIImage output into a pixel (or color) which can be used as an argument for another custom CIFilter or Kernel.

Comment: I guess I was wrong, sorry. Are you trying to get a `CIColor` from a 1x1 pixel?

Comment: That's correct. I updated the post with more clarification.